# IE9 and modernizr 2.6.1, dropdownlist does not open

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4, modernizr

Dropdownlist on my MVC4 application using modernizr 2.6.1 running on IE9 shows unexpected behavior. It works fine on FF and Chrome. It also works when modernizr 2.6.1 is unreferenced.

The problem is that when a page loads up some of dropdownlists open up by clicking on them, they also accept keyboard inputs but some of them don't accept inputs(mouse and keyboard) at all. But after few random clicks, some of them start working when they get and loss focus few times.

How do i troubleshoot this problem?

**Edit**

It is confirmed that something is wrong with modernizr, i removed all the scripts except modernizr and the problem is there and the problem is gone when just modernizr is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modernizr does not work with IE, simple !!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a simalar problem with IE, Modernizr och jQuery UI Slider element. Works in Firefox, but not in IE. If I remove Modernizr, it works in IE as well.